# SharePoint DateTimeControl styling is getting out in google chrome

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, sharepoint-server

I am using a SharePoint DateTimeControl in my web part solution in SharePoint 2013. it is working fine in Internet Explorer:

[image]

but when I open the same page in Google Chrome, it looks like the following:

[image]

Please help me resolve this issue

Thanks

Following is the HTML:

```
   <SharePoint:DateTimeControl runat="server" ID="txt_expectedReturnDate" />
```

**Update:**

I have added the following in Page Load:

txt_expectedReturnDate.DatePickerFrameUrl = ResolveUrl(SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_layouts/15/iframe.aspx");

but now it's showing the following in Chrome while it's fine in internet explorer:

[image]

I am also facing the following issue:
[Chrome is opening Local Host site with HTTPS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264583/chrome-is-opening-local-host-site-with-https)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `DatePickerFrameUrl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/15/iframe.aspx %>"` within the `<SharePoint:DateTimeControl>` tag and check again.

Comment: I am unable to build the project after adding <SharePoint:DateTimeControl DatePickerFrameUrl="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/_layouts/15/iframe.aspx %>" runat="server" ID="txt_expectedReturnDate"  />, the initializeControl method is getting removed after adding this so all the controls on this page are seem to be "does not exitsts"

Comment: please see my update and help me