# Chrome is opening Local Host site with HTTPS

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, web-part, browser-compatibility, chrome

In a SharePoint Development Environment whose server name is "dev", the site is deployed on the port 80.

I am accessing the site in Internet Explorer using dev:80 then internet explorer automatically creates URL : http://dev/pages/

when I try http://dev:80 in Chrome, it generates HTTPS i.e. https://dev/ and then it shows this site can't be reached

However I can access the site in Chrome using `http://localhost/` but there are some problems being generated if I use `Localhost/` because it keeps generating HTTPS for the files linked in the Project

For Example I am currently facing the following problem:
[SharePoint DateTimeControl styling is getting out in google chrome](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264057/sharepoint-datetimecontrol-styling-is-getting-out-in-google-chrome)

Please help me resolve this 
Thanks

**Update**

I've placed a different host name in the hosts file refer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/16851/change-name-of-website-for-intranet-purposes):

`127.0.0.1 imcportal-dev`, it is now asking for authentication in Google Chrome but not accepting the User ID and Password. I am unable to Login into the site now from any browser

**Update 2:**

I have configured alternate access mapping and given the alternate name as "abc" to access the site on the local machine and as well as on LAN:

[image]

On the Local Server, it says `This page can't be displayed`

On the Other system on the network, it says Servers IP address could not be found:

[image]

I have tried putting the same in Intranet,Custom, Extranet Categories but the issue is same

**If I Put IP Address in place of abc, it works fine although I need to use the name to access the site instead of IP Address**

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

`.dev` is a bad choice for a local tld as it's a "real" tld and [owned by google](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#NS/.dev). Chrome (since version 63) will **always** use https to access `.dev` domains.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47768289/chrome-redirects-dev-to-https) for the same problem.

I'd suggest you use a different domain. [`.localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.localhost), [`.example`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.example), [`.invalid`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.invalid) and [`.test`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.test) were designed for local development. Also [`.local`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local) works good.

Comment: this is the server name, there is no any domain attached to this site. can you please help me resolve this using IIS

Comment: Kindly see my update in the question

Comment: @AlinaAnjum your extra updated info is caused by loop back checking.  In a dev environment, you should disable loop back checking, otherwise, NTLM auth fails because the host name does not match the server name.

Comment: And if you "only" add a different hostname in the `host`-file, SharePoint might not "answer" - you'd need an AAM for that (see the answer above)

Comment: @Nils please look into the following https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264649/rename-sharepoint-development-server

Comment: @Nils I have configured alternate access mapping to resolve this but still facing issues, kindly see my Update 2

Comment: Now, something seems to be wrong with the DNS settings. Try setting up DNS, or modify the `hosts` file.

Comment: Can you suggest me the steps? do any kind of change or update is required in IIS?

Comment: If I Put IP Address in place of abc, it works fine although I need to use the name to access the site instead of IP Address

Comment: Open `c:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` and add a line for abc

Comment: I've added 127.0.0.1 abc
192.168.10.32 abc in this file, it's now accessible on Local Machine but continuosly asking for authentication again & again and still not accessible from LAN

Comment: If you need the server available in the lab you need to update the settings on your DNS server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94994/discussion-between-alina-anjum-and-nils).

Comment: Please can you provide the details of the steps I need to take to get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by Alternate Access Mappings for the particular Zone.

I would suggest taking a look at the AAM setup to see if there is anything that will trigger a protocol redirection.

The basics of AAM are documented here:-
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings

Comment: AAM will not trigger automatic redirections.

Comment: @James kindly look into the following https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264649/rename-sharepoint-development-server

Comment: @James I have tried alternate access mapping, kindly see my update