# Rename SharePoint Development Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-farm, sharepoint-administration

My SharePoint development server name was "Dev", I was facing many issues as it is Google Standard Domain as mentioned in the following:

[Chrome is opening Local Host site with HTTPS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/264583/chrome-is-opening-local-host-site-with-https/264587?noredirect=1#comment281299_264587)

Now I have renamed this Server. Kindly do let me know the complete set of steps further required to make everything working in SharePoint

Answer (score 2):

- [Change Alternate Access Mappings in Central Administration](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/configure-alternate-access-mappings)
- [Check if the hostname is used in IIS-Binding](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-2013-changing-the-url-of-existing-web-application/)
- [Change Search Content Sources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/add-edit-or-delete-a-content-source) and perform FullCrawl
- [Check & maybe change MySite Host Location in UserProfileService](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/86aff8/how-to-change-the-my-site-host-location-in-sharepoint-2013/)